# React prop based rendering not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel-mix

So I have this component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import NeoHeader from './header/NeoHeader';
import NeoLoginModal from './modal/NeoLoginModal';

class Neo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {loginModal: false};
    }
    render() {
        return( <NeoHeader/> { this.state.loginModal ? <NeoLoginModal /> : null })
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Neo/>,
  document.getElementById('react-wrapper')
);
```

and as you can see, I'm trying to show the component NeoLoginModal when a state prop is set to true. However, building with Laravel mix gives an unexpected token error at the `{this..}` start. This is documented in multiple places as a correct way to do this, so what's the error about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not within the Laravel Mix but with your component HTML structure. In `React` you can't render siblings as first-level elements. In order to make your code work you should wrap both child components with a parent tag, for example:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <NeoHeader />
            { this.state.loginModal ? <NeoLoginModal /> : null }
        </div>
    );
}
```